# R lookup chart from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, crosstab

I want to transform a `data.frame` in **R** from looking like this:

```
W   Well Name    Ct (dR)
A1  F_0.2,R_0.2  23.72
A2  F_0.2,R_0.2  23.82
A3  F_0.2,R_0.4  22.87
A4  F_0.2,R_0.4  23.1
B1  F_0.4,R_0.2  23.74
B2  F_0.4,R_0.2  24.01
B3  F_0.4,R_0.4  22.86
B4  F_0.4,R_0.4  22.79
C1  F_0.6,R_0.2  23.5
C2  F_0.6,R_0.2  No Ct
C3  F_0.6,R_0.4  23.03
C4  F_0.6,R_0.4  22.61
D1  F_0.8,R_0.2  23.83
D2  F_0.8,R_0.2  23.67
D3  F_0.8,R_0.4  22.48
D4  F_0.8,R_0.4  22.41
```

into this:

```
    1       2       3       4
A   23.72   23.82   22.87   23.1
B   23.74   24.01   22.86   22.79
C   23.5    No Ct   23.03   22.61
D   23.83   23.67   22.48   22.41
```

Even better, like this:

```
        R_0.2   R_0.4   R_0.6   R_0.8
F_0.2   23.72   23.82   22.87   23.1
F_0.4   23.74   24.01   22.86   22.79
F_0.6   23.5    No Ct   23.03   22.61
F_0.8   23.83   23.67   22.48   22.41
```

There are actually 12 columns and 8 rows, but you get the point :)
Also - what is this kind of data sorting called?

Comment: Please check the second output with the 'Well Name' column in your initial data.  It is not matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `separate` the 'W' column into two, then drop the  'Well Name' column with `select` and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   separate(W, into = c("W1", "W2"), sep="(?=\\d+)") %>%
   select(-`Well Name`) %>%
   spread(W2, `Ct (dR)`)
#  W1     1     2     3     4
#1  A 23.72 23.82 22.87  23.1
#2  B 23.74 24.01 22.86 22.79
#3  C  23.5 No Ct 23.03 22.61
#4  D 23.83 23.67 22.48 22.41
```

---

It seems that the 'Well Name' column values in the input dataset is not matching with the expected output.  Assuming that the values are as in the data below

```
df1 %>%
   separate(`Well Name`, into = c("WN1", "WN2"), sep=",") %>% 
   select(-W) %>% 
   spread(WN2, `Ct (dR)`)
#    WN1 R_0.2 R_0.4 R_0.6 R_0.8
#1 F_0.2 23.72 23.82 22.87  23.1
#2 F_0.4 23.74 24.01 22.86 22.79
#3 F_0.6  23.5 No Ct 23.03 22.61
#4 F_0.8 23.83 23.67 22.48 22.41
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(W = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", 
"B4", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"), `Well Name` = c("F_0.2,R_0.2", 
"F_0.2,R_0.4", "F_0.2,R_0.6", "F_0.2,R_0.8", "F_0.4,R_0.2", "F_0.4,R_0.4", 
"F_0.4,R_0.6", "F_0.4,R_0.8", "F_0.6,R_0.2", "F_0.6,R_0.4", "F_0.6,R_0.6", 
"F_0.6,R_0.8", "F_0.8,R_0.2", "F_0.8,R_0.4", "F_0.8,R_0.6", "F_0.8,R_0.8"
), `Ct (dR)` = c("23.72", "23.82", "22.87", "23.1", "23.74", 
"24.01", "22.86", "22.79", "23.5", "No Ct", "23.03", "22.61", 
"23.83", "23.67", "22.48", "22.41")), .Names = c("W", "Well Name", 
"Ct (dR)"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

>>>> df1<- read_excel("heatmapfor.xlsx", col_types = c("text", "text", "text"))

>>> the your lines
>>>Error in select(., -`Well Name`) : unused argument (-`Well Name`)

Comment: @ChristianOlesen  May be you need to check the column names.  In your input data, there are spaces in the column names, but once you read in `R`, it could be changed to `.`  You can try the code with the data I showed here

Comment: now i get this message: "Error in select(., -W) : unused argument (-W)". But thank you so much for you helping me - I've been trying to figure this out the whole morning (Denmark)

Comment: @ChristianOlesen  In the original dataset, you had a column named `W`.  Please check your column names in 'df1'  after reading i.e. `colnames(df1)` and see if that name is there.  BTW, I am using `dplyr_0.7.4` and `tidyr_0.7.2`

Comment: @ChristianOlesen  It is working for me.  Could that due to the version of your packages?   I commented about the package versions above

Comment: I'm gonna try updating :)

Comment: I got it working! It was the dplyr package that was making trouble (or some other package masking the select function) :D Thank you so very much!